# "too many variables specified" error with predict following logit

Tags: stata, predict

I have a panel of data (firm-years) that span several countries. For each country I estimate a `logit` model using the first five years then I use this model to `predict` probabilities in subsequent years. I `foreach` loop over the countries and `forvalues` loop over the subsequent years.

The first few countries work well (both estimations and predictions), but the fifth country's first out-of-sample prediction fails with:

```
Country: United Kingdom
Year: 1994
too many variables specified
r(103);
```

The model fits and 1994 has enough data to predict a probability. My `predict` call is:

```
predict temp_`c'`y' ///
    if (country == "`c'") ///
        & (fyear == `y'), ///
    pr
```

Do you have any ideas what could cause this error? I am confused because `logit` and `predict` work elsewhere in the same loop. Thanks!

FWIW, here's the .do file.

```
* generate table 5 from Denis and Osobov (2008 JFE)
preserve

* loop to estimate model by country
levelsof country, local(countries)
foreach c of local countries {
    display "Country: `c'"
    summarize fyear if (country == "`c'"), meanonly
    local est_low = `r(min)'
    local est_high = `=`r(min)' + 4'
    local pred_low = `=`r(min)' + 5'
    local pred_high = `r(max)'
    logit payer size v_a_tr e_a_tr re_be_tr ///
        if (country == "`c'") ///
            & inrange(fyear, `est_low', `est_high')
    forvalues y = `pred_low'/`pred_high' {
        display "Country: `c'"
        display "Year: `y'"
        predict temp_`c'`y' ///
            if (country == "`c'") ///
                & (fyear == `y'), ///
            pr
    }
}

* combine fitted values and generate delta
egen payer_expected = rowfirst(temp_*)
drop temp_*
generate delta = payer - payer_expected

* table
table country fyear, ///
    contents(count payer mean payer mean payer_expected)

*
restore
```

---

**Update**: If I `drop (country == "United Kingdom")`, then the same problem shifts to the United States (next and last country in panel). If I `drop inlist(country, "United Kingdom", "United States")` then the problem disappears and the .do file runs through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using country names as part of the new variable name that `predict` is creating. However, when you get to "United Kingdom" your line

```
predict temp_`c'`y'
```

implies something like

```
predict temp_United Kingdom1812
```

But Stata sees that as two variable names where only one is allowed.

Otherwise put, you are being bitten by a simple rule: Stata does not allow spaces within variable names.

Clearly the same problem would bite with "United States".

The simplest fudge is to change the values so that spaces become underscores "_". Stata's OK with variable names including underscores. That could be

```
gen country2 = subinstr(country, " ", "_", .)
```

followed by a loop over `country2`.

Note for everyone not up in historical details. 1812 is the year that British troops burnt down the White House. Feel free to substitute "1776" or some other date of choice.

(By the way, credit for a crystal-clear question!)

Comment: Thanks, Nick, for the crystal clear answer! I'm still not sure if loops are a net gain for me. :)

Comment: And I should have anticipated the 1812 response.

Comment: There's general discussion at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/index.html In your case, there is a clear gain from intelligible variable names, but otherwise `egen`'s `group()` function allows a clean approach to a loop over groups defined by one or even more variables.

Comment: FWIW to later readers, I changed the `local macro` for each country rather than the country variable: `local c_alt: subinstr local c " " "_"`

Comment: I would have used `strtoname` to remove other problematic characters. Any reason you preferred `subinstr`, Nick?

Comment: Fr.: Just my familiarity with that function. `strtoname()` is a more recent addition to Stata. It's a good solution here too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an another approach to your problem. Initialise your variable to hold predicted values. Then as you loop over the possibilities, `replace` it chunk by chunk with each set of predictions. That avoids the whole business of generating a bunch of variables with different names which you don't want to hold on to long-term.

```
* generate table 5 from Denis and Osobov (2008 JFE)

preserve
gen payer_expected = . 

* loop to estimate model by country
levelsof country, local(countries)
foreach c of local countries {
    display "Country: `c'"
    summarize fyear if (country == "`c'"), meanonly
    local est_low = `r(min)'
    local est_high = `=`r(min)' + 4'
    local pred_low = `=`r(min)' + 5'
    local pred_high = `r(max)'
    logit payer size v_a_tr e_a_tr re_be_tr ///
       if (country == "`c'") ///
       & inrange(fyear, `est_low', `est_high')
    forvalues y = `pred_low'/`pred_high' {
        display "Country: `c'"
        display "Year: `y'"
        predict temp ///
            if (country == "`c'") ///
            & (fyear == `y'), pr
        quietly replace payer_expected = temp if temp < . 
        drop temp 
   }
}

generate delta = payer - payer_expected

* table
table country fyear, ///
     contents(count payer mean payer mean payer_expected)

*
restore
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I've used that approach in the past, but have recently become `if' averse due to slow speeds doing regressions by country and year elsewhere (and miss R's ability to split once, apply, and combine). Is my aversion unfounded here? Most likely, I suspect the `egen rowfirst` operation just hides the repeated `if' calls.

Comment: Doing things `if` isn't fast because Stata tests every observation to see if it qualifies. Selecting a small subset from a big dataset therefore carries a relatively large overhead. You can make it faster by doing an equivalent `in` but that requires careful code. Or you can throw out the data you don't want and then read it back in again. My gut feeling here is that what I suggest in the second answer is no slower than what you are doing already. The accountancy on fast and slow should always include programmer time in getting the code right....